# SQL count how many male and femal in the same type

Tags: mysql

[image: sample database]

Above is my participants table and my problem is I want to count how many male and female are the same type of participant. Below is the code I have that count how many participant per type.

```
SELECT type_parti, COUNT(1) FROM tbl_participants GROUP BY type_parti
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional sum

```
SELECT type_parti, 
       sum(sex = 'm') as males,
       sum(sex = 'f') as females 
FROM tbl_participants 
GROUP BY type_parti
```

Comment: Yes this works great! Thanks